# Javers:Ignore specific fields in Value Object while comparing two jsons

Tags: diff, javers

I am trying to compare two jsons, expected and the API Response using Javers, as part of testing. I want the comparison to exclude the ID parameters that are dynamically generated by response.

My VO is like

```
public class expectedResponse{

@DiffIgnore
private String id;
private String name;

}
```

Both my expectedResponse- which is read from excel file and the actual response from API are deserialized into this format and then both the responses are compared.

```
JsonNode expectedOutput = mapper.readTree(expected.toString());
JsonNode apiResponse = mapper.readTree(actual.toString());
diff=javers.compare(expectedOutput, apiResponse);
```

But this comparison doesn't exclude/ignore the ID field. Any Idea how I can get it to work? I want only the ID field excluded in comparison results, diff in name should be listed.

Also question 2> I am trying to list the changes from diff

```
if (diff.hasChanges()) 
    {               

    List<ValueChange> changes=diff.getChangesByType(ValueChange.class);
    for (ValueChange change : changes) 
    {
    logger.info(change.getPropertyName()+ "||" +change.getLeft().toString() + "||" +change.getRight().toString());
```

**change.getPropertyName()**- doesnt print the property's name but simply prints **"_value" as its value.**

Can you pls help in identifying what is going wrong with the code and how can I get this fixed? I am not finding much useful documentations about Javers anywhere in google. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare you domain object instead of object with `JsonNode` class, look that `@DiffIgnore` annotation is present only in your domain class and there is no connection between `JsonNode` and `ExpectedResponse`, thats why Javers doesn't know to ignore this field.

To summarise, your code should looks like this:

```
ExpectedResponse expectedOutput = ... 
ExpectedResponse apiResponse = ...
diff=javers.compare(expectedOutput, apiResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. That exactly was the mistake I had made, which was staring on the face all along. I had them converted as String which was causing all the trouble. Your help is much appreciated! Thank you.